# Multivariate regressions with qualitative features

Tags: regression, least-squares

In the example from **An Introduction to Statistical Learning** Book about interpretations of coefficients in existence and regression with quantitative and qualitative variables (Example south, east and west region) in chapter 3, topic 3.3. It is said that there must always be the number of levels -1 as dummy variables with the interpretation of the coefficients being

yi = β0 +β1 xi1 +β2 xi2 +ϵi

β0 +β1 +ϵi > if south

β0 +β2 +ϵi > if west

β0 +ϵi > if east

But if 3 dummy variables (β1, β2, β3) were created for the three levels, would the interpretation be wrong not considering one of the levels as a baseline? I ask why it is said that "there must always be one less dummy variable than the number of levels. The level without dummy being the baseline" and I always see dummy with all levels.

And when there is more than one categorical variable with more than two levels, what should the baseline β0 be?

Answer (score 2):

The number of dummy variables must be 1 less than the number of categories. This helps to avoid the "**Dummy Variable Trap**", which is a fancy way of saying "**to avoid perfect multicollinearity**". If you include all categories as dummies, you can perfectly predict one category from the other, causing multicollinearity.

So, we treat any one category as a baseline and predict the other categories with the help of their coefficients.

Suppose, you have two categorical variables of Gender (male/female) and Region (north/south). Your equation could look something like this:

**Y = B1 + B2(Gender) + B3(Region) + e**

where, Gender = {1 = female; 0 = male} and Region = {1 = north; 0 = south}

In this example,

- your baseline "B1" = male from south.
- B1 + B2 = female from south
- B1 + B3 = male from north
- B1 + B2 + B3 = female from north

Comment: How create this baseline when two categorical features have +2 levels ?

Comment: The process can be extended. Suppose you also have to include a dummy for West and East in regions. You can simply include 2 more variables where, "Region1 = {1=East; 0=south}" and "Region2 = {1=West; 0=south}". Your baseline stays the same (male from south), but you get 2 more coefficients B4 and B5 for East and West. As an example, B1+B2+B4 = female from east